# Telerik WinForm Controls not showing Design-Time

Tags: c#, winforms, reference, assemblies, gac

I am having trouble dragging controls from Tool Box into Design-View for Windows Form using Telerik References. Instead of controls showing up in the Design-View, it shows up in the component box on the bottom.

I tried adding the application extensions in the assembly using gacutil.exe.
I also tried removing all reference and using it again.
All the Versions for the reference are the same. So no version mismatch issue.

Anyone have better idea? or Solutions for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Telerik controls are, well, *special*.  Their sales staff is quite capable, can't get them to stop spamming me.  Not what you need, you'll need find out the merits of their support staff at the company's support web site.  Start here: http://www.telerik.com/consulting/support.aspx

Comment: I agree with Hans, Telerik and http://www.mindscapehq.com/ have fantastic support...

Comment: You can find an answer to this issue in this link: [RadControls for WinForms are not loaded at design-time](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/winforms/details/radcontrols-for-winforms-are-not-loaded-at-design-time "Change")